# Apache Olingo4 ExpressionVisitor

Tags: java, odata, olingo

How to pass a raw expression to ExpressionVisitor implementation of `Odata4` using `olingo4`. This is how it was done in `olingo2` [JDBC Visitor Filter](http://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata2/tutorials/Olingo_Tutorial_AdvancedRead_FilterVisitor.html)

```
String rawExpression = "'a' eq 'b' or ('c' eq 'd' and 'b' eq 'd')";
FilterExpression expression = UriParser.parseFilter(null, null, rawExpression);
String whereClauseSimple = (String) expression.accept(new JdbcSimpleStringVisitor());
```

Answer (score 1):

There is currently (released version 4.2.0) no API exposure for this functionality.

You could set a dependency to the server-core module directly and call 
"new Parser(edm,odata).parseUri(final String path, final String query, final String fragment)"

or use the filter parser direclty by creating a UriTokenizer and then calling "FilterParserparse(UriTokenizer tokenizer, final EdmType referencedType,
      final Collection crossjoinEntitySetNames, final Map aliases)"

Comment: Thanks @chrisam ! I am trying to generate Elasticsearch query from `odata4` $filters. I am not implementing the whole `oData 4` protocol. I am looking for a way to  parse the $filter string and get the ExpressionVisitor working.  Is there a way I can do it without passing edm or EdmType in FilterParserparse  or Parser  method in Olingo 4.2.

Comment: @Tirtha No there is not. The parser requires an EDM in V4.